# How to add_filter html template to middle of content

Tags: functions, filters, hooks

I've been trying to add some of the Items to the middle of WordPress content using add_filter.  The code is successfully added Ads code to the top of WordPress content, but not the meddle.

Here is code I used:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'bbtre_amazon_content_filter');
function bbtre_amazon_content_filter($content){

if(is_singular('post')){
    $count = explode('</p>', $content);
    foreach($count as $i => $paragraph){
        $count = $i+1;
        }

    $content = explode('</p>', $content);

    foreach( $content as $index => $paragraph){
        if(trim($paragraph)){
            $content["{$index}"] .= '</p>';
        }

        if($index == intval($count/2)){
            $ads = bbtre_the_amazon_items();
            $content["{$index}"] .= $ads;
        }
    }
}

$content = (is_array($content)) ? implode($content) : $content;

return $content;
}
```

inside the bbtre_the_amazon_items();

```
function bbtre_the_amazon_items(){
include(get_stylesheet_directory() .'/inc/reshare/templates/ads/amazon.items.php');
}
```

inside the template page:

```
<div class="amazon-item-wrap"><?php echo bbtre_get_amazon_items_list(); ?></div>
```

Anyone please kindly help me to solve the problem, please.

Note: the above code works fine when I use

```
$content["{$index}"] .= '<p>Hello World</p>';
```

instead of:

```
$content["{$index}"] .= $ads;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `add_filter()` instead of `apply_filters()`. `apply_filters()` is used to apply the filter that's been registered with `add_filter()`. Please check the following code for the solution -

```
function bbtre_amazon_content_filter( $content ) {
    if ( ! is_single() ) {
        return $content; // Return early if not single post
    }

    // Paragraphs array without the closing tag
    $paragraphs       = explode( '</p>', $content );
    // Number of paragraphs in $paragraphs
    $paragraphs_count = count( $paragraphs );
    // Middle index of $paragraphs
    $middle_index     = absint( floor( $paragraphs_count / 2 ) );
    // New content string
    $new_content      = '';

    for ( $i = 0; $i < $paragraphs_count; $i++ ) {
        if ( $i === $middle_index ) {
            // Add custom content in the middle of post contents
            $new_content .= bbtre_the_amazon_items();
        }
        // Append the missing closing p tag
        $new_content .= $paragraphs[ $i ] . '</p>';
    }
    return $new_content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'bbtre_amazon_content_filter' );
```

Comment: additional to using `add_filter()` make sure to rewrite the function`bbtre_the_amazon_items()` to return the result instead of echoing it. possibly by using object buffering.

Comment: I'm sorry. I did not edit my code here. Actually, I used add_filter, but it did not work.

Comment: @obiPlabon ! Thanks so much for your answer. I found the solution. I need to return the out put using ob_get_clean();